# Accessibility/Voice over Requirement on UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: accessibility, uiactivityindicatorview, voiceover

I am trying to provide an accessibility label for UIActivityIndicatorView (which is created programmatically in my view controllers viewDidLoad). I am setting the accessibility label as:

```
myIndicatorView.accessibilityLabel = @"Please wait, processing"
```

But when I run the application, the voice over always reads "in progress". I tried to debug on simulator using the accessibility inspector, but everytime the indicator view is in focus, it has the label as "in progress". I assume, "in progress" is default voice over text for activity indicators view, But I can not change this label. I am wondering if the activity indicator view's accessble label can never be changed.
If somebody came across this issue and found a workaround, then please help me.

Comment: In Xcode 8.1, in the visual editor (Is it still called Interface-builder?) There's no "Accessibility" section for my UIActivityIndicatorView. (other buttons, labels, and other views DO have such section). Was it decided by Apple that UIActivityIndicatorView should remain generic, unless subclassed and overridden by code? There's not even a label to say "video loading progress indicator" as the role (whereas "button" would be narrated on buttons, etc.). How can I customize this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not that you're not changing it.  It's that, in the background, as the status of the progress indicator changes, iOS backend updates the label, to the appropriate status.  This is overriding whatever you changed it to, because it is likely applying its own update after you change the status.

I would just leave this alone.  "Please wait, processing" provides no additional information as compared to "In progress".  And "In progress" is the way VoiceOver users will be accustomed to hearing an "In progress" state progress indicator announce. Changing this announcement is to a non-sighted user, what changing the image to a revolving Mickey Mouse head would be to sighted one.

If you MUST change this, what you want to do, is instead of setting the property, override the implementation of the property's getter method.  To do this provide a custom implementation of UIActivityIndicatorView that does the following.

```
@interface MyActivityIndicator : UIActivityIndicatorView

@end

@implementation MYActivityIndicator

- (NSString*)accessibilityLabel {
    if (self.isAnimating) {
        return NSLocalizedString("ACTIVITY_INDICATOR_ACTIVE", nil);
    } else {
        return NSLocalizedString("ACTIVITY_INDICATOR_INACTIVE", nil);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree about just leaving the default label

Comment: Thanks a lot man !!! The only reason I wanted to override the accessibility behaviour for activity indicator is to let the impaired person know if a service call is being made. Instead of saying In Progress, I wanted to do something more specific like "account details being retrieved" or something ilke "the list call is made.. please wait for response" (more specific to the web API call type)

Answer (score 0):

## `UIActivityIndicatorView` subclass in Swift

The implementation of the `accessibilityLabel` getter in `UIActivityIndicatorView` is dynamic based on the state of the control. Therefore, if you set its `accessibilityLabel`, it may change later.

The following `UIActivityIndicatorView` subclass overrides the default implementation of `accessibilityLabel`. It is based on the answer by @ChrisCM in Objective C.

```
class MyActivityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView {

    override var accessibilityLabel: String? {
        get {
            if isAnimating {
                return NSLocalizedString("ACTIVITY_INDICATOR_ACTIVE", comment: "");
            }
            else {
                return NSLocalizedString("ACTIVITY_INDICATOR_INACTIVE", comment: "");
            }
        }

        set {
            super.accessibilityLabel = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

In my app, the activity indicator is visible on the screen and to VoiceOver only when it is animating. Therefore, I only need one `accessibilityLabel` value. The following subclass uses the default, dynamic implementation of `accessibilityLabel` unless set explicitly. If set, it uses that value regardless of the state.

```
class MyActivityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView {

    private var accessibilityLabelOverride: String?

    override var accessibilityLabel: String? {
        get {
            if accessibilityLabelOverride != nil {
                return accessibilityLabelOverride
            }

            return super.accessibilityLabel
        }

        set {
            accessibilityLabelOverride = newValue
        }
    }
}

// Example use
let activityIndicatorView = MyActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
activityIndicatorView.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("ACTIVITY_INDICATOR", comment: "")
```